# Pass variable in API url in java .

Tags: java, rest, api

I want to pass the **"host name"** , **"port"** , "**cluster**" in a particular API HTTP call. How to pass the variables in the url ?
Any help is much appreciated .

**Code :**

```js
 int port = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("sd.port"));
 System.out.println("port no : " + port);
 String hostName = prop.getProperty("sd.hostname");
 System.out.println("host name : " + hostName);
 
 String cluster = app_prop.getProperty("ClusterName");
 System.out.println("cluster name is  : " + cluster);
 
 
 
 try {

  
 String url ="https://hostName:port/api/scanCluster?cid=cluster&mode=1";
```

**A seen in the above url , I am trying to pass "hostName" , "port" and "cluster" . Please help .**

Comment: You are already using examples of String appending with `+ port`,  `+ hostName`, `+ cluster` and you just need to do that for the url as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use String concatenation (with the `+` operator) to combine String literals and variables:

```
String url = "https://"+hostname+":"+port+"/api/scanCluster?cid="+cluster+"&mode=1";
```

Comment: Side note: Many say, that you should use a StringBuffer / StringBuilder instead of the + concatination. This is only true for when building up string in loops or more complex constructs. In this case, you can absolutly use the + concatination, as the compiler will optimize the code and use a StringBuilder. You can see this by checking the ByteCode.

Comment: @f1sh thanks a ton . I am ashamed of myself . That was dumb on my part .